# Should I join a character and its accessories into one object for an animation?

Tags: modeling

I'm very new to blender, I made a low poly character that I want to rig for animation the character is a scuba diver. I made the character first then the accessories such as scuba mask and tanks and so on. My question is.
Should I join the accessories to the character or not join them, if they are not joined is it then harder to make a animation. Do I rig the character without the accessories first then add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

There's no real right or wrong answer here. If your character is really low poly, and all the accessories are permanently attached, then joining the objects is fine. However, keeping the separate also works well.

The advantage to keeping things separate is it allows you to edit any object at any point. It also makes assigning materials easier, and can even make rigging a bit easier. The reason for this is you can parent an object directly to a bone. This is really useful for objects like a scuba tank or mask that won't have to deform.

At the end of the day, I'd just pick one and give it a shot. You can always separate or combine objects if you think another way would work better. We're always here for any specific questions you may have along the way too.

Comment: Very good, perfect answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this answer is enough, please accept it by clicking the little check mark to the left, so that the question is considered answered.